# Java: Iterating through an Array List

Tags: java, string, object

I have an ArrayList containing names of instantiated objects that I want to execute the method 'count' on. I'm unsure if/how to do that, though. I have a loop to scan through the array list, and added pseudocode with what I'm trying to achieve.

```
    n = 0;
    while(n <= arrayList.size()){
        (arrayList.get(n)).count();
    }
```

I'm new to java and am not sure this is possible, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to increment your index `n`.

Comment: Wait, the list contains objects that support the method `count()`, right? What did you mean by _containing names of instantiated objects?_

Comment: Names as strings. I.e. "kiwi" would be an object that could execute kiwi.count. I got a good answer from raffian though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler way to do it...

```java
ArrayList<MyObject> list = ...
for( MyObject obj : list)
  obj.count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to do so:

Basic1:

```
n = 0;
while (n < arrayList.size()) {
    (arrayList.get(n)).count();
    n++;
}
```

Basic2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    (arrayList.get(i)).count();
}
```

Better1:

```
for(ClassTypeOfArrayList item: arrayList) {
    item.count();
}
```

Better2:

```
Iterator iterator = arrayList.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: you forget the OO way , `for(Iterator it = arrayList.iterator();it.hasNext();){ Object o= it.next();}` or with a while

Comment: In fact I viewed this problem at the point of a green hand. If you are new to java, using the first two is a fast way to get thing done. When you are familiar with java you may do anything you what. Thx.